# how to make jquery autocomplete simplify

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I use `jquery autocomplete` and it look like my code, to call the plugin, not good. is there any more simple way to call `jquery autocomplete`

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#m_occupation").autocomplete("search/moccupation.php", {
        selectFirst: true
 });
 $("#foccupation").autocomplete("search/f_occupation.php", {
        selectFirst: true
 });
 $("#g_address").autocomplete("search/g_address.php", {
        selectFirst: true
 });
 $("#relationship").autocomplete("search/relationship.php", {
        selectFirst: true
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've got isn't really terrible. If you're only ever initializing these autocompletes one time, then it's pretty readable overall, although you do have some repetition.

1. **Cache your jQuery objects for future use.** In your snippet above, you only reference each jQuery object (e.g., `$("#m_occupation")` ) once, but in a real webapp, there's a pretty good chance you'll use it more. Caching helps reduce the number of jQuery finding operations, and is a good practice to adopt even though it's not likely to increase performance for a user noticeably.
2. **Cache your options objects.** You're repeating your option declaration multiple times; just declare a single `autocompleteOptions` object and be done with it.
3. **Refactor initialization into a function.** If you're really feeling like the autocomplete initialization is ugly, or complex, or subject to frequent edits, make it a single function. Future global edits to initialization can be made one time rather than multiple times.

A redo of your code taking those into account would look like:

```js
var initAutocomplete = function($el, dataUrl) {
  var autocompleteOptions = { selectFirst: true };
  $el.autocomplete(dataUrl, autocompleteOptions);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  var $m_occupation, $foccupation, $g_address, $relationship;

  $m_occupation = $('#m_occupation');
  initAutocomplete($m_occupation, "search/moccupation.php");

  $foccupation = $('#foccupation');
  initAutocomplete($foccupation, "search/f_occupation.php");

  $g_address = $('#g_address');
  initAutocomplete($g_address, "search/g_address.php");

  $relationship = $('#relationship');
  initAutocomplete($relationship, "search/relationship.php");
});
```

You could technically optimize further by using a single string to represent the DOM ID and URL from which you gather the data, but in my experience, that breaks down in maintenance. So I wouldn't couple those too tightly.